# After Creating a new Process in Bash kill Error

Tags: bash

I want to run a python script as new process. The python script should be run with a bash script that looks like that

```sh
python test3.py
PID=$!
sleep 59
kill $PID
```

but after a 59 seconds i get an error
`kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]`

Comment: There's something weird with your code. Unless you fork your python process, it will run until the end and the `kill` would try to kill a no longer existent process. but the error would be different :-?

Comment: my python script has while true loop so it schould never end itself

Comment: seems  `&` is missing at the end of python command (so that the command could be launched in background), otherwise the last forked pid `$!` may be empty, and result is the error you get

Comment: After adding the `&` it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> seems `&` is missing at the end of python command (so that the command could be launched in background), otherwise the last forked `pid $!` may be empty, and result is the error you get – Nahuel Fouilleul 1 hour ago

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `pkill` or `killall`